# Define two methods with same parameter type

Tags: c#, .net, methods, parameters, overloading

Today I ran into a scenario where I have to create a method that share the same `name, params count and params types` with existent one, Something like this:

```
public static Department GetDepartment(string departmentName)
{
  //LOGIC
}

public static Department GetDepartment(string employeeID)
{
  //LOGIC
}
```

at first glance I just said why not to name it with a different name and get things done, but I couldn't! I do want to maintain the readability of my code i'm working on, I want it to be `overloaded` to the first one,
so I said why not to add a fake parameter just to workaround this issue from the compiler Point of view.

```
 public static Department GetDepartment(string employeeID, object fakePassWtEver)
    {
      //LOGIC
    }
```

What is the best practice for this case? I see all the ways can let my code run, but none of them satisfied me

Comment: the idea of the fake parameter is really bad... to have multiple methods with same name parameter types should be different, you can have once string and once object but this is not good either because every time you will pass a string the one with object will not be called... as Jon suggested, just use two different method names all the time you can't have properly different parameter types...

Comment: the down vote is ok with me as along as it associated with a comment! is it wrong to ask what you have in mind..

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Maintaining readability is precisely *why* you should rename it:

```
Department GetDepartmentByName(...)

Department GetDepartmentByEmployeeID(...)
```

Now whenever you call the method, it's *absolutely obvious* which one you mean. That's very much *not* the case if you overload the method instead.

I've become increasingly reluctant to overload over time - there are [quite a few subtle issues](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx), and readability very often goes down.

Comment: That's certainly the correct answer, but a little explanation might be helpful so he can see why it is the way you say it is.

Comment: @jnm2: Which bit do you believe is unclear? What needs explaining? Isn't it obvious that `GetDepartmentByName(value)` is clearer in meaning than `GetDepartment(value)`?

Comment: _I_ see it as self-explanatory, but he might not.  I remember a time years ago when it would not have been obvious at all for me.  The thing is, not everyone is born with these instincts - there's always a first time.  So since I don't know his context, I would make sure my answer would be helpful to a wider audience.  It doesn't hurt to reinforce concepts, for that matter.  But that's just me.  I might be totally wrong here.

Comment: @jnm2: But I'm not sure how I could make it clearer, to be honest... which bit would not have been obvious to you, and what *would* have made it obvious? I'm all for improving answers where possible...

Comment: The edit you've done since I first commented is more helpful because it draws attention to why the first example is good and why the second is not.  Similar to how I see readability, I'm all for making it easier for people to understand and remember.  If I had asked I might have liked to hear more about what happens if you do it the wrong way so that the principle becomes more intuitive.  Otherwise I might go on feeling like I would still prefer it, which would influence my decisions.  It's sort of like 'seeing' math rather than just having the facts.

Comment: @jnm2: I suspect I'd made the edit before you actually posted your comment, but obviously after you'd loaded the page - which would explain the disconnect :)

Comment: Some bit late here but i see you don't see the people logic by asking such question. you re right for the answer. but not offering the best solution here which should be one function GetDepartment(string key). and the logic inside will look in both list and return the value it find. in case of having same key in Name and EmployeID (which is hard) it should take one of them or have other logik'

Comment: @fekirimalek: That sounds like a really, really bad idea to me. What if you have a department name the same as an employee ID? There's nothing in the question that suggests that would be prohibited. Further more, it means that someone who *thinks* they're looking up by an employee ID, but happens to pass something that isn't a known employee ID but *is* a known department name ends up with something they didn't expect. I would never suggest that as a solution. Feel free to add an answer yourself, but I for one would downvote that idea.

Answer (score 6):

You could update your method signatures and make your code more readable at the same time by doing something like the following.

```
public static GetDepartmentByName( string departmentName )

public static GetDepartmentByEmployeeId( string employeeId )
```

Personally I feel that adding verbosity to code helps others that come later understand what's going on. It also helps make your methods "read" more easily.

Answer (score 4):

Define 2 methods:

1. `public static Department GetDepartmentByDepartmentName(string departmentName)`
2. `public static Department GetDepartmentByEmployeeID(string employeeID)`

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to delegate to other methods if you can somehow distinguish between an employee ID and a department name by examining the argument.

```
public static Department GetDepartment(string employeeIdOrDepartmentName) {
    if (LooksLikeEmployeeID(employeeIdOrDepartmentName))
        return GetDepartmentByEmployeeID(employeeIdOrDepartmentName);
    else
        return GetDepartmentByDepartmentName(employeeIdOrDepartmentName);
}

private static Department GetDepartmentByEmployeeID(string employeeId) {
    /* ... */
}

private static Department GetDepartmentByDepartmentName(string departmentName) {
    /* ... */
}
```

You should only do this if you absolutely cannot add another method for clarity - the other answers are 100% on point.

Comment: I was wondering when this would come up.  This model could be good for interpreting user input, but it should not be used internally.  Extra calculation and complexity will lead to slower and likely buggier code.  In fact, interpreting user input should only be done in one place and does not warrant maintaining its own function in the framework.  In other words, the top method does not belong  with the other two.  It belongs in the UI section of the program.

Comment: Yes, this is a 'last resort' solution.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but it is possible, I had the exact same scenario today (constructor overloading, thus can't change name). Here is how I did it, small hack but it lets me have all my LINQ predicates that are related in the same place:

```
public BusinessStructureFilterSpecification(int responsibilityTypeId, bool dummy1 = true) : base(x => x.ResponsibleGroups.Any(x1 => x1.ResponsibilityTypeId == responsibilityTypeId))
{
    AddIncludes();
}

public BusinessStructureFilterSpecification(int userId, string dummy2 = "") : base(x => x.ResponsibleUsers.Any(x1 => x1.UserId == userId))
{
    AddIncludes();
}
```

Now the trick is to call them using parameter names like so:

```
if (responsibiltyTypeId.HasValue && !userId.HasValue)
    spec = new BusinessStructureFilterSpecification(responsibilityTypeId: responsibiltyTypeId.Value);

if (!responsibiltyTypeId.HasValue && userId.HasValue)
    spec = new BusinessStructureFilterSpecification(userId: userId.Value);
```

Comment: With all respect, I would decline such approach in the code review. It's misleading, causing non-obvious overload resolution, and not much help from compiler to figure out why that code breaks. It's too C-plus-plusish, sorry.

Comment: @YurySchkatula So you would create a new class for exactly the same purpose?

Comment: Just to change names to be unique. Unlike Swift, C# doesn't include metadata like param names into the signature so we have to live with that.

Comment: @YurySchkatula these are constructors that all point to a base constructor, I can't change the name unfortunately.