# Handling Functions with Same Signature but Different Parameter Meanings

Tags: c#, architecture, software-design

I've been reading [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by Robert C. Martin. In it, he states that a function should use the minimal number of parameters as necessary and that function names should follow a project-wide naming convention, while avoiding gratuitous context.

For example, if I have a simple class I wrote for this question, `Car`:

```
public class Car
    {
        internal string make { get; set; }
        internal string model { get; set; }

        public Car(string make, string model)
        {
            this.make = make;
            this.model = model;
        }
    }
```

And a class `Cars`:

```
public class Cars
{
    internal List<Car> cars { get; set; }

    public Cars(List<Car> cars)
    {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public Car GetCar(string make)
    {
        foreach (Car car in cars)
        {
            if (car.make == make) return car;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Car GetCar(string model)
    {
        foreach (Car car in cars)
        {
            if (car.model == model) return car;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Obviously this does not compile, as the functions named `GetCar` have the same function signature.

Normally I might have gotten around this by renaming the functions `GetCarByMake` and `GetCarByModel`, or something similar, but the text seems to indicate that this is not best practice. Other times, I may have added an additional unused parameter to differentiate them.

My next thought was to create a class for each property in `Car`; have a class for `Make` and `Model` that contains the string property. However, this seems to introduce unnecessary overhead.

I am curious then, how can I implement / name multiple functions that do conventionally similar things, have the same parameter data types, and output the same data type, without having different function names? Also, I am not interested in additional function overloading or polymorphism for this question, or similar topics; I want to know the answer with regards to the classes as they currently are without major changes. The only answer I can currently see is to create classes for each property.

Please let me know if any clarification or changes are needed.

EDIT:
Just as some added information, this is purely an academic exercise. Professionally, I would simply create the methods with different names and be done with it. As stated in the comments, it's simple, maintainable, and it works.

Comment: For what it is worth, if you aren't willing to add interfaces etc - I'd give the methods different names. It is nice, simple, easy to read and grok, and it compiles.

Comment: @mjwills Good point. I've reworded my question to remove the opinion based aspects and make it a straightforward programming question. Thanks for the headsup! On a side note, I think that having different method names is the best route. But, I wanted to see if another way was possible.

Comment: There can be different approaches, all valid and clean. Some will use Method overloading, some can use different methods, some can use default valued parameters with dynamic inline Linq queries. All of them can be clean if  code can be maintained with proper documentation and naming conventions. It is not measurable, unless some one collects source code from around the globe to analyse the patterns and design principals.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858838/define-two-methods-with-same-parameter-type

Comment: @RyanSchlueter I am aware that I can rename the methods and be fine (as evidenced in my question). My question is if it is possible to maintain the same method name, without using dummy parameters, and avoid using classes for my properties.

Comment: @HiteshGaur The Linq route seems interesting. I agree with your statement that there are many valid routes. I usually just rename the method as I described in my question, but I thought I'd post this as an academic exercise after reading some of Clean Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have multiple methods with the same “name” and signature in the same class via explicit interface implementation:

```
public interface IFindByMake
{
     Car GetCar(string make);
}

public interface IFindByModel
{
     Car GetCar(string model);
}

public class Cars : IFindByMake, IFindByModel
{
    internal List<Car> cars { get; set; }

    public Cars(List<Car> cars)
    {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    Car IFindByMake.GetCar(string make)
    {
        foreach (Car car in cars)
        {
            if (car.make == make) return car;
        }
        return null;
    }

    Car IFindByModel.GetCar(string model)
    {
        foreach (Car car in cars)
        {
            if (car.model == model) return car;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above code does compile; however, you’ll notice that if you declare a variable of type `Cars` there will be no method `GetCar` available. You can only call the method if you cast to one of the two interface types or declare the variable as one of the two types.

```
var cars = new Cars();
((IFindByMake)cars).GetCar(“Ford”);
```

Or

```
IFindByModel cars = new Cars();
cars.GetCar(“Mustang”);
```

Otherwise how on earth would the compiler know which method to call?

Comment: Great answer Dave! I thought about it over night and concluded that a method similar to this would be the only realistic way to do it. However, using this method obviously runs into the issue that you can only use the method for whichever interface you initially cast the `Cars` variable to. You would not be able to use the other method. Like you said, though, there needs to be some way to differentiate the functions so the compiler can tell the difference. The only other way I know of to do that would be to differentiate them at the function level, which is synonymous with renaming them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq as mentioned below

```
public Car GetCar(string make, string model)
{

    return cars.Where(w=>  (string.IsNullOrEmpty(make) || w.make == make) &&(string.IsNullOrEmpty(model) || w.model == model)).Select(s=>s).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Let's say I wanted a list of cars where the model was `null` and I didn't care about the make. Can this query do that?

Comment: Thanks Hitesh! I've chosen to mark Dave's answer as the best answer because it best answers my question as I asked it, but I do think that your method is the more practical route. Using interfaces, like I mentioned in another comment, removes some of the needed functionality.

Comment: @mjwills: it's a sample query to show that this is one of way to use, modify logic as per requirements, the way information is stored. if any additional parameters are needed, add them to achieve desired result. It depends on how 'null' is treated, for above query, 'when nothing is passed in the parameter, get all records', was presumed requirement.

Comment: @Jack: thank you. I do not mind about marking Dave's answer as best answer. I use mixture of approaches, based on what makes sense to have a good organised code. I prefer to use interfaces, to distinguish behavior in two or more types of entities. If I have vehicles that need different implementation for search parameters by make or model, I think I will use interface. For filtering with properties, I may use one big dynamic linq or may use private functions with different method names to be invoked by a public method with both parameters.